# Passing Data between react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, react-component

I am trying to make simple calendar. In my calendar, I have day, day-names, month and month-names component and all I am accessing it on main calendar. When initial load it will show current month calendar.

Now when I select month from month-name component want to pass to month component and then pass to day component to render dates.

I try to use call back function but it is not helping me out

Whole react component is here **https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z2278r**

`Day component`

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
import * as React from 'react'

import { showComponent } from '../../../../models'
import { MonthNames } from './'
import styles from './Calendar.module.scss'

interface IDatePickerMonthsProps {
  changeMonthComponent: (showComponent: showComponent, monthNo: number) => void
}

interface IDatePickerMonthsState {
  dateObject: moment.Moment,
  monthNo?: number
}

export class DatePickerMonths extends React.Component<IDatePickerMonthsProps, IDatePickerMonthsState> {

  constructor(props: IDatePickerMonthsProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dateObject: moment()
    }
  }

  public render() {
    const monthPicker =
      <div className="datepicker-days">
        <table className={styles.table}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronLeft" title="Previous Month" onClick={this.onPrev}></span></th>
              <th className={styles["picker-switch"]} data-action="pickerSwitch" colSpan={5} title="Select Month">
                {this.year()}
              </th>
              <th><span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronRight" title="Next Month" onClick={this.onNext}></span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={7}>
                <MonthNames changeMonthComponent={() => this.showDays(this.state.monthNo)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    return (monthPicker)
  }

  private year = () => {
    return this.state.dateObject.format("Y");
  };

  private onPrev = () => {
    this.setState({
      dateObject: this.state.dateObject.subtract(1, "year")
    });
  };
  private onNext = () => {
    this.setState({
      dateObject: this.state.dateObject.add(1, "year")
    });
  };

  private showDays = (monthNo: number) => {
    console.log(monthNo)
    this.setState({ monthNo: monthNo })
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo)
  }
}
```

`Month name component`

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
import * as React from 'react'

import { showComponent } from '../../../../models'

interface IMonthNamesProps {
  changeMonthComponent: (showComponent: showComponent, monthNo: number) => void
}

export class MonthNames extends React.Component<IMonthNamesProps, {}> {
  private monthshort: string[] = moment.monthsShort();

  constructor(props: IMonthNamesProps) {
    super(props)
  }

  public render() {
    let monthshortname = this.monthshort.map((month, monthNo) => {
      return <span key={monthNo} onClick={() => this.showDays(monthNo)}>{month}</span>;
    });
    return monthshortname
  }

  private showDays = (monthNo: number) => {
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo)
  }
}
```

`Month component`

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
import * as React from 'react'

import { showComponent } from '../../../../models'
import { MonthNames } from './'
import styles from './Calendar.module.scss'

interface IDatePickerMonthsProps {
  changeMonthComponent: (showComponent: showComponent, monthNo: number) => void
}

interface IDatePickerMonthsState {
  dateObject: moment.Moment,
  monthNo?: number
}

export class DatePickerMonths extends React.Component<IDatePickerMonthsProps, IDatePickerMonthsState> {

  constructor(props: IDatePickerMonthsProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dateObject: moment()
    }
  }

  public render() {
    const monthPicker =
      <div className="datepicker-days">
        <table className={styles.table}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronLeft" title="Previous Month" onClick={this.onPrev}></span></th>
              <th className={styles["picker-switch"]} data-action="pickerSwitch" colSpan={5} title="Select Month">
                {this.year()}
              </th>
              <th><span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronRight" title="Next Month" onClick={this.onNext}></span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={7}>
                <MonthNames changeMonthComponent={() => this.showDays(this.state.monthNo)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    return (monthPicker)
  }

  private year = () => {
    return this.state.dateObject.format("Y");
  };

  private onPrev = () => {
    this.setState({
      dateObject: this.state.dateObject.subtract(1, "year")
    });
  };
  private onNext = () => {
    this.setState({
      dateObject: this.state.dateObject.add(1, "year")
    });
  };

  private showDays = (monthNo: number) => {
    console.log(monthNo)
    this.setState({ monthNo: monthNo })
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo)
  }
}
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what exactly is not working? what are you trying to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my issue, with the help of **see sharper ** and thanks support and up votes.

Now back to my problem. My calendar was initially loading correctly but when I change month and year in MonthName component (i.e. child component) pass up to DayPickerMonths (i.e. parent component) and then up to Calendar component (i.e. grand parent component) then down to DatePickerDays component (i.e. child component to Calendar & sibling to  DayPickerMonths)

Visually looks like this
[image]

So start with child (i.e. MonthName)

**function**

```
private showDays = (monthNo: number) => {
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(monthNo)
  }
```

**call in render**

```
public render() {
    let monthshortname = this.monthshort.map((month, monthNo) => {
      return <span key={monthNo} onClick={() => this.showDays(monthNo)}>{month}</span>;
    });
    return monthshortname
  }
```

**DayPickerMonths (i.e. Parent)**

```
<MonthNames changeMonthComponent={(monthNo) => this.showDays(monthNo, this.state.dateObject.year())} />

private showDays = (monthNo: number, year: number) => {
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo, year)
  }
```

**Calendar (i.e Grand Parent)**

```
<DatePickerMonths
              changeMonthComponent={(childData, monthNo, year) => this.changeMonthComponent(childData, monthNo, year)} />

private changeMonthComponent = (childData: showComponent, monthNo: number, year: number) => {
    this.setState({ showComponent: childData, monthNo: monthNo, year: year })
  }
```

**DayPickerDays (i.e. Child to Calendar & sibling to DayPicker)**

```
private showMonths = () => {
    this.props.changeComponent(showComponent.Months)
  }
public componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ dateObject: this.state.dateObject.month(this.props.monthNo).year(this.props.year) })
  }
```

I have update my for this over here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z2278r

> > But still it have issue that ***when year is change in DayPickerDays component it did not reflect in DayPickerMonths*** and cumbersome to pass data, we should use **React context** to make it global and simple. I will soon update this answer once I will make provider as I need to go for doctor appoinment for my eyes checkup

Answer (score 3):

See this bit: `<MonthNames changeMonthComponent={() => this.showDays(this.state.monthNo)} />`

and this bit: `this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo)`

The problem there is that the inner component calls the function changeMonthComponent, but the arguments are thrown away by the parent. The MonthNames component needs to do something with the arguments getting passed back up:

`<MonthNames changeMonthComponent={(days, monthNo) => this.showDays(monthNo)} />`

(Roughly - I'm not digging into all aspects of your code, so I don't know exactly what you want to do with the days parameter that my suggestion is ignoring.)

Comment: I have updated code in my repo but still I could not succeed

Comment: Do you understand the explanation I gave? You must pass the properties up to the parent and use them there. If you don't understand the principle it's hard to work out the kinks.

Comment: I did that but in MonthName function it does not pass the value

Comment: I did like this <MonthNames changeMonthComponent={(monthNo) => this.showDays(monthNo)} /> but in private showDays = (monthNo: number) => {
    console.log(monthNo)
    this.props.changeMonthComponent(showComponent.Days, monthNo)
  } console.log gives always 0

Comment: Yes, but I have fixed it. My problem was that I was passing 1 parameter rather than two parameter due to that it was giving is me issue. Now my issue how I will pass it to DayPickerDays and use it is days to render with new month days

Comment: and Yea my stackblitz is uptodate

Comment: Well you have the idea - pass props up the component tree using callbacks, and down using props. Just make sure you hook up the functions and their arguments correctly. Please mark as answer if it helped, and post a new question if you hit a different issue.