# How to pass data to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So i am creating a film site where users can search a film and then click the card to get more details about the film. I cannot get the details part of the film to go to the details page. I have an `onclick` for the details of the film to be pulled from the api using the film id that is already there `movieresults.id`. I have a `NavLink` on the image part of the film card this is where the user would click and it would go to the details page where the details of the film would appear but i am struggling to get that data to that page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Card Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import placeholder from '../Assets/Placeholder.jpg'
import {Button, Alert, Nav, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import '../sass/custom.scss'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faStar, faPlay, faHeart, faShare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { FilmPage } from './FilmPage'

export const MovieCard = ({movieresults}) => {
    const [trailer, setTrailer] = useState();
    const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

    const onClick = e => {
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieresults.id}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (!data.errors) {
                console.log(data)
                setContent(data);   
            }else{
                <Alert variant="danger">Error</Alert>
            }
        })
    }

    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieresults.id}/videos?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        if (!data.errors) {
            setTrailer(data.results[0]?.key);   
        }else{
            <Alert variant="danger">Error</Alert>
        }
    })

    return (
        <div className="movie-card">
            <div className="poster-container">
                <span className="rating translate-middle rounded-pill">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} className="star"/>
                    {movieresults.vote_average}
                </span>
            {movieresults.poster_path ? (
                <Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact={true} to={{pathname:"/film", state: content }} className="poster-link" >
                <img className="poster" 
                src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${movieresults.poster_path}`} 
                alt= {movieresults.title}
               />
               </Nav.Link>
            ) : (
                <img className="poster"
                 src={placeholder} 
                 alt= {movieresults.title}
                />
            )}
            </div>
            <div className="content-container">
                <b className="title mobile-text">{movieresults.title}</b>
                <p className="desc mobile-text">{movieresults.release_date}</p>
                <div className="card-btn">
                    <Button className="btn btn-secondary watch-btn" target="__blank" href={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${trailer}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} /> Trailer</Button>
                    <div className="icons">
                        <a href className="icon-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} onClick={onClick}/> </a>
                        <a href className="icon-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShare} /> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div key={content.id}>
                    <h3 className="title">{content.title}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Film Page Component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const FilmPage = ({content}) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <h1>Film Page</h1>
            <h1>{content.id}</h1>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781640/passing-data-between-react-components)

Comment: This: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @RandyCasburn how would i implement that into my code?

Comment: Read, understand and implement the concepts discussed in the documentation that I linked for you. Here it is again just in case you missed it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? From your project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: @DrewReese `cineflex@0.1.0 /Users/imad/repos/CHT2531_FE/cineflex
                        └── react-router-dom@5.3.0`

Comment: Ok, just verifying the RRD version to know if you were passing route state correctly to begin with. Yes, you can use the `useLocation` hook to access the passed routed state. Use caution tough if your UI allows for direct navigation to the route/path rendering this `FilmPage` component as `location.state` will be undefined and throw an error if you access more deeply.

Comment: Instead of doing the onclick and fetching the film details on the card component i passed the film id to the film page and did a fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are not able to take the data from the `Film Page Component` when you pass them from `Card Component`.
To solve it, you have to use the `useLocation` hook in the child component to take the state from the `Nav.Link`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useLocation } from 'reacr-router';

export const FilmPage = ({content}) => {

    const location = useLocation();    

    return (
        <Container>
            <h1>Film Page</h1>
            <h1>{location.state.content.id}</h1>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Using the `useLocation` like that, you can easily retry the state you passed.

Comment: Yes that is the issue i cannot get the data from the card component `content` to display in the film page component. I tried using the react router method  ```<Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact={true} to={{pathname:"/film", state: content }} className="poster-link" >```  but in the film page it says `compnent.id is undefined`

Comment: On the `Card Component` try to pass the state as `state: { content: content }` instead of `state: content`

Comment: tried ```<Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact={true} to={{pathname:"/film", state: {content:content} }} className="poster-link" >
``` but it still gives `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` in the film page

Comment: Your `content` state in the `Card Component` has something inside? At this point, I think the error is inside the state

Comment: ```const onClick = e => {
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieresults.id}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (!data.errors) {
                console.log(data)
                setContent(data);   
            }else{
                <Alert variant="danger">Error</Alert>
            }
        })
    }``` yes that is setting the content state

Comment: You call the `onClick` only when you click on the heart icon, if I understand your code. Is there the possibility that when you click on the `Nav.Link` the state is empty?

Comment: ``` <Nav.Link as={Link} exact={true} to={{pathname:"/film", state: {content:content} }} onClick={onClick} className="poster-link" >
``` I missed that thank you. It still gives `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` on the film page when clicked

Comment: That's because when you fill the state, it doesn't fill instantly, it's better call on `useEffect` when you load initially the page and inside fill the `state`.

Comment: I forgot to add the useLocation in the film page component but your solution have fixed it thank you

Answer (score -1):

Hope it Helps You..

Parent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child';

const Parent = () => {
const data = "Hello Everyone";
    return(
        <div>
        <Child data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = (props) => {
    return(
    <h2> {props.data} </h2>
    );
}

export default Child;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./index.css";
import Parent from './Parent'

const App = () => {
return (
    <div className="App">
    <Parent/>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```